# Get ListView from a Layout Using RemoteViews

Tags: android, google-glass, remoteview

I am working on a java based Google Glass service and wanted to add a listview fro some objects but unable to get and work with ListView using RemoteViews. So is there anyway i could add list in the card using remote views?

Comment: I am not sure for Google Glass service (never worked before) but I remember I also got stuck one day and fortunately I bookmarked the page which helped me to understand the process. Its here: http://laaptu.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/android-app-widget-with-listview. Hope you solve your issue and it works with google glass

Comment: Post up what you have done so far. We can't help if we don't know where you are stuck

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider displaying your information using a widget other than a `ListView`. The user experience on Glass is different than that of Android, so a `ListView` will look out of place there and the user would be unable to interact with it in a meaningful way on a live card.

Comment: This isn't true. You don't interact with a listview the same as a phone but that doesn't mean it's out of place. The widget you see after you say "ok, glass" is a listview.

Comment: The widget you see after you say "ok, glass" is not a ListView. The stock ListView in Android is not styled for Glass and does not support interaction that the "ok, glass" menu has, like head-scrolling, that would make it usable with the Glass form factor. If you would like to see this added, please file an issue in our issue tracker (https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

Comment: @TonyAllevato: please suggest any other thing than a list view. This is my scenario -> Tap a Card -> Takes you to a listview (ideally) -> Then  take user to a card navigated from the list view. How can I handle this on  glass....do u want me to take user to a different scroll view instead of a list...

Comment: You should use `CardScrollView` for long lists of items that you want the user to be able to scroll through.